# How I can block space from the name?

Tags: php, substr

Currently, I'm trying to block from my clients use space at the name when they create an account in my website.

They can register as "Fred ", it shouldn't be possible, should be only "Fred" and not with the space after the name.

I tryed using:

```
if(substr($name_to_check, -1) == " ")
    return false;
```

But seems it is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `trim()` it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use php `trim()`.

trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

if Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string

```
ltrim($name_to_check);
```

if Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

```
rtrim($name_to_check);
```

if you want to remove some section.Remove characters from both sides of a string ("He" in "Hello" and "d!" in "World"):

```
<?php
$str = "Hello World!";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo trim($str,"Hed!");
?>
```

then output will be

```
Hello World!
llo Worl
```

something like this

```
<?php
$str = " Hello World! ";
echo $str.": Without trim";
echo "<br>";
echo trim($str).": With trim";
?>
```

then output will be

```
Hello World! : Without trim
Hello World!: With trim
```

for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) instead. Doing so is the standard way, and also prevents you from using unnecessary `if`s.

Example usage of `trim()`:

```
<?php

$text   = "\t\tThese are a few words :) ...  ";
$binary = "\x09Example string\x0A";
$hello  = "Hello World";
var_dump($text, $binary, $hello);

print "\n";

$trimmed = trim($text);
var_dump($trimmed);

$trimmed = trim($text, " \t.");
var_dump($trimmed);

$trimmed = trim($hello, "Hdle");
var_dump($trimmed);

$trimmed = trim($hello, 'HdWr');
var_dump($trimmed);

// trim the ASCII control characters at the beginning and end of $binary
// (from 0 to 31 inclusive)
$clean = trim($binary, "\x00..\x1F");
var_dump($clean);

?>
```